# Kubernetes kubectl copy command failing

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a pod running python image as 199 user. My code app.py is place in `/tmp/` directory, Now when I run copy command to replace the running `app.py` then the command simply fails with file exists error.

[image]

Comment: make sure user 199 has write access to /tmp directory in container.

Comment: reason I used /tmp directory was, everyone has access. Further I had tried changing owneship of directory to 199.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try to use the `--no-preserve=true` flag with `kubectl cp` command. It will pass `--no-same-owner` and `--no-same-permissions` flags to the `tar` utility while extracting the copied file in the container.

GNU [`tar` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Dealing-with-Old-Files.html) suggests to use `--skip-old-files` or `--overwrite` flag to `tar --extract` command, to avoid error message you encountered, but to my knowledge, there is no way to add this optional argument to `kubectl cp`.

Comment: [a_ansible@master1 out]$ kubectl cp app.py 103000-pras-dev/simplehttp-777fd86759-w79pn:/tmp/ --no-preserve=true


              Error: unknown flag: --no-preserve

Comment: Please upgrade 'kubectl' client to newer version. This flag was introduced for the first time in v1.13.0-alpha.1.

Comment: [a_ansible@master1 out]$ kubectl cp app.py 103000-pras-dev/simplehttp-777fd86759-w79pn:/tmp/ no-preserve=true


tar: app.py: Cannot open: File exists
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
command terminated with exit code 2

Comment: Well, your toolset on the container where you want copy files to seems to be very limited. I have no problems with overwriting existing files on public toolbox container. Btw. what exactly container are you using in your Pod spec ?
You can try to workaround it with move command:
'kubectl cp LICENSE default/toolbox:/tmp/LICENSE2' &
'kubectl exec toolbox -- mv -f /tmp/LICENSE2 /tmp/LICENSE'

Comment: @Nepomucen I'm facing the same issue. I'm using --no-preserve option as well but the issue still persists. Could you please advise, if we can try any other option or how to troubleshoot further?

Comment: @prashant did you got any solution for it.